# Determine $\alpha >0$ for which $\iint_Af(x,y)^\alpha dx \, dy < +\infty$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> Let $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: 0<x<1, 0< y < \sqrt{x}\}$ and $f \colon A \to\mathbb R$ a continuous function s.t.
>   $$
> \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \le f(x,y) \le\frac{2}{x^2+y^2}
> $$ 
>   for every $(x,y) \in A$. Determine the set of value $\alpha >0$ such that 
>   $$
> \iint_Af(x,y)^\alpha dx \, dy < +\infty.
> $$

The function $t\mapsto t^\alpha$ is monotone (increasing) when $\alpha>0$. Therefore, using the hypothesis we get
$$
\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^\alpha} \le f(x,y)^\alpha \le\frac{2}{(x^2+y^2)^\alpha}
$$ 
for every $(x,y) \in A$.
Integrating we get 
$$
\iint_A \frac{dx \, dy}{(x^2+y^2)^\alpha} \le \iint_A f(x,y)^\alpha dx \, dy\le\iint_A\frac{2 \, dx \, dy}{(x^2+y^2)^\alpha}
$$
If we pass to polar coordinates, we have
$$
\iint_A \frac{1}{\rho^{2\alpha-1}} \le \iint_A f(\rho \cos{\vartheta},\rho \sin{\vartheta})^\alpha \rho \, d\rho \, d\vartheta \le \iint_A \frac{2}{\rho^{2\alpha-1}} \, d\rho \, d\vartheta
$$

Now we have to write the set $A$ using the polar coordinates, but this is quite difficult. What can we do? I think that the first and the third integrals are improper in $0$ with respect to $\rho$. Therefore I think we should ask at least $2\alpha-1<1$ i.e. $\alpha<1$.

I think $\alpha=1$ doesn't work: indeed, we have 
$$
\begin{split}
\iint_A f(x,y) dx \, dy & \ge \iint_A\frac{\, dx \, dy}{(x^2+y^2)} \\
& = \int_0^1 dx \, \int_0^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{dy}{x^2+y^2} = \\ 
& = \int_0^1 dx \, \frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{dy}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^2} =\\
& = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\arctan{\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)}dx = +\infty
\end{split}
$$
because 
$$
\frac{1}{x}\arctan{\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)} \sim_{x=0} \frac{c}{x}
$$
whose integral in $0$ diverges.

What do you think? Is it correct? How can we prove it formally?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha <1$ we have $2\alpha<2$ and
\begin{equation}
\int_{A} f(x,y)^{\alpha} \le \int_{B_1} \dfrac{2}{|X|^{2 \alpha}} < \infty.
\end{equation}
If $\alpha >1$ we have $2\alpha>2$ and considering $B \subset A$ we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{A} f(x,y)^{\alpha} \ge \int_{B} \dfrac{1}{|X|^{2 \alpha}} < \infty.
\end{equation}
To $\alpha=1$ see for one idea.
[Example that $u\in W^{1,2}$, but $u \notin W^{1,3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178576/example-that-u-in-w1-2-but-u-notin-w1-3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot understand what happens if $\alpha >1$: would you mind fixing the typo? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I did a type.

Comment: I think you should edit still one typo: I think you mean that if $\alpha > 1$ then the integral is $>+\infty$, hence it diverges. In other words, the only thing we have to do is discussing what happens when $\alpha=1$. Thanks also for the reference, I'll read it!

Comment: Following the link, I got an interesting idea and I wrote down the case $\alpha=1$ in the OP. Would you like to give a look at it, please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Only note that $\int_0^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{dy}{x^2+y^2}= \frac{1}{x}\arctan{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$, $\int_0^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{dy}{x^2+y^2} \neq \frac{1}{x^2}\arctan{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$ and see $\underline{\mbox{Modern Techniques and Their ApplIcations. Folland corollari 2.52}}.$

Comment: Of course, you are right. Thanks a lot also for the bibliographical reference!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $0 < \rho < 1$, $0 < \vartheta < \pi/4 \implies (\rho, \vartheta) \in A \implies 0 < \vartheta < \pi/2$.

Comment: So we can write $\iint_A \frac{1}{\rho^{2\alpha-1}}d\rho d\vartheta \le \int_0^1 \frac{d\rho}{\rho^{2\alpha-1}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\vartheta = \int_0^1 \frac{d\rho}{\rho^{2\alpha-1}}\frac{\pi}{2} < \infty$ iff $\alpha<1$. Am I right? Thanks for your answer!